# Error Message `code.google.com/p/go.crypto/pbkdf2 file not found`

Tags: juju

I am new to GO language. I want to make a juju charm-store server but it's giving me this error:

```
imports code.google.com/p/go.crypto/pbkdf2: exec: "hg": executable file not found`
```

this is the location charm-store (https://github.com/sajith4u/charmstore). This command failed to compile:

```
go get -u -v -t github.com/juju/charmstore/..
```

Does anyone know what is the reason is for this?

Comment: Your environment is missing mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

The command `hg` comes from mercurial. `which hg` should report `/usr/local/bin/hg`. If this gives ....

1. a different result you need to put that directory into your PATH variable. `echo $PATH` will show the current path. [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) will show how to include that directory to the current PATH.
2. an empty results you need to install mercurial. You can use the [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mercurial) how to install it. In short:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mercurial meld
   ```

   The website has 2 comments on this:

   - If it fails reporting dependencies, please locate the packages and install them. If it reports any other issues, please resolve them.
   - If you cannot resolve the issue, please refer the mailing list archive of those packages.

---

With

```
    hg version
```

you can check if it reports a version number. And if that does not report an error your command will work.